# Generate random ASCII character

Tags: random, scheme, lisp, ascii

I need to generate a random ASCII letter (upper or lowercase) or character (but not number) in scheme, and I was wondering what the appropriate way to do that was. Currently I've got the code

```
(define a 1)
(define b 16)
(define (s8 a b)
  (when (<= a b)
    (if (= (mod a 8) 0)
      (write "h")
      (write a))
    (s8 (+ a 1) b)))
(s8 a b)
```

which works (no errors) but instead of printing a random ascii letter/character, I get "h", because I didn't know how to do that. I googled around but couldn't find a thing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
(define random-char
  (let* ((chars '("a" "e" "i" "o" "u"))
         (len (length chars))) 
    (lambda ()
      (list-ref chars (random len)))))
(define a 1)
(define b 16)
(define (s8 a b)
  (when (<= a b)
    (if (= (mod a 8) 0)
      (random-char)
      (write a))
    (s8 (+ a 1) b)))
(s8 a b)
```

gives error

```
1234567
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "random" [s8, s8, s8, s8, s8, s8, s8, s8, random-char]
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel! Scheme has built-in procedures for generating random values.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to put all acceptable chars in a list and then randomly pick one from them:

```
(define random-letter
        ; this is to avoid redefining the list of acceptable letters every time
  (let* ((chars '("a" "e" "i" "o" "u"))
        ; and this is to pre-calculate the length
         (len (length chars))) 
    (lambda () ; the actual procedure, it doesn't require arguments
      (list-ref chars (random len))))) ; pick a random index from list
```

Make sure to add all needed chars in the list. Using the procedure is as easy as this:

```
(random-letter)
=> "u"
```

Comment: I put the definition at the beginning and then put in `(random-letter)` instead of `(write "h")` and it gave the error `1234567
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "random" [s8, s8, s8, s8, s8, s8, s8, s8, random-char]`.

Comment: That means that your interpreter doesn't have a `random` procedure or is named differently. What interpreter are you using? check the documentation to find the correct procedure to use, or alternatively download Racket, which is really nice for learning. Also, I'm not sure _how_ you're executing the code, the displayed output doesn't make sense - you should clear everything and just copy-paste the above snippets

Comment: I'm using repl.it, an online interpreter. It says "BiwaScheme Interpreter version 0.6.4 Copyright (C) 2007-2014 Yutaka HARA and the BiwaScheme team". I edited with the code I ran.

Comment: Working with online editors is not a good idea when learning Scheme, not all implement the whole standard and certain features and/or procedures will be missing. Do yourself a favor and download Racket ;)

Comment: Its not just the interpreter that doesn't have random, Scheme isn't defined with it. There is [SRFI-27](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-27/srfi-27.html) which has `random-integer` and `random-real`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you might do this in an industrial-strength Scheme-derived language: in particular Racket.  It assumes various functionality which
you might need to implement in a more bare-bones Scheme, such as functions
to make strings, to convert between characters and integers, and a PRNG
(as well as curry).

If your scheme is missing some of this functionality you may have to write it, which might be educationally interesting, but nothing else.

```
(define latin-alpha-string
  ;; This assumes that a-z are a sequence of adjacent, increasing
  ;; character codes, as are A-Z, but nothing about their relative values
  (let ([lca (char->integer #\a)]
        (uca (char->integer #\A)))
    ;; build-string makes a string by calling a function which takes an index
    ;; and returns the character at that index.
    (build-string (+ 26 26)
                  (λ (i)
                    (integer->char
                     (if (< i 26)
                         (+ lca i)
                         (+ uca (- i 26))))))))

(define (random-string-char s (rand random))
  ;; The general case: return a random element of a string.  rand, if provided,
  ;; should be a function of one argument, i, which returns a (pseudo-)random
  ;; integer in [0, i).
  (string-ref s (rand (string-length s))))

(define random-latin-alpha-char
  ;; and here's a curried version of the above for latin-alpha strings
  (curry random-string-char latin-alpha-string))
```